# SQL select records only from last 5 minutes

Tags: python, mysql

I want to get the records from last 5 minutes. I am currently using this code, which I got from this site:

```
select * from table where timestamp between curtime() and timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute))
```

But it doesn't work for me, it returns all my records at intervals of 5 minutes. For example, I'll have several records with a timestamp at 2014-07-30 15:40:02, then I'll get a 5 minute gap and get several records with a time stamp of 2014-07-30 15:45:02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your where clause:

```
where timestamp between curtime() and timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute))
```

In this case, the first bound is *larger* than the second, because you are subtracting 5 minutes from the current time.  This actually should not match anything, because:

```
where x between y and y - 5
```

should always return an empty set.  The bounds are in order.  Perhaps swapping them will help:

```
where timestamp between timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)) and curtime()
```

However, if you don't have future timestamps, just do:

```
where timestamp >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where timestamp >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
read=("""select * from table where timestamp >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute))""")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where timestamp between curtime() and DateADD(minute, -5, curtime());
```

Comment: @Nishu: note that it's better to mark as code by indenting lines by 4 spaces. Highlight the code, then click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K.